# Invalid diffID error on loading docker image

Tags: docker

I saved a docker image on an Ubuntu 16.04 installed computer. I'm trying to load that image on an Ubuntu 18.04 installed computer. But it fails. The error message is:

```
0f5ff0cf6a1c: Loading layer    126MB/126MB
f1c896f31e49: Loading layer  15.87kB/15.87kB
51db18d04d72: Loading layer  14.85kB/14.85kB
f51f76255b02: Loading layer  5.632kB/5.632kB
174a611570d4: Loading layer  3.072kB/3.072kB
e80ca7c265eb: Loading layer  31.23kB/31.23kB
9b1416aedd41: Loading layer  660.6MB/660.6MB
849bc8cbb157: Loading layer  3.072kB/3.072kB
47b41f9e6cc5: Loading layer  902.7MB/902.7MB
5be8865ab1cd: Loading layer  3.584kB/3.584kB
68da9ff1a51a: Loading layer  299.3MB/299.3MB
189d27e41182: Loading layer  149.7MB/149.7MB
dba13b27fe2e: Loading layer  11.92MB/11.92MB
8636f1ad2902: Loading layer  574.2MB/574.2MB
18ec18aa7286: Loading layer  662.8MB/662.8MB
invalid diffID for layer 14: expected "sha256:18ec18aa72862417ebf82cd1f1d412c1318b952fa8b31f0fe7e14b158c5937d8", got "sha256:2ae68c07ebcbdff48ac2ad8d419282fd2e1fd85aba3287c025f8f6c0bdca18d4"
```

Comment: I solved the problem my self. I just saved my docker image one more time and reload it.

Comment: Any solutions? I have tried to reload but same error occurred.

Comment: @HerilMuratovic The solution that I commented is worked for me.

Comment: The problem for me was in disk space.

Answer (score 0):

I had the invalid diffID expected xxxx error and couldn't find any solutions online
Seems like the only way to go around the problem is that if your image is exported, try to make it lighter (mine was 16gb and i was expecting many layers)

Do docker import instead if it's possible

And if those 2 ways didn't help, try to recreate the image..